# crontab doesn't run a bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I read a lot of other topics and try many stuff, but I still doesn't work.

I have this simple run2.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 my_script.py
wait;
sudo mv /home/ubuntu/test_code/csv_created_by_python_script.csv /var/www/html
```

It works perfectly when I go to the directory and wrote

```
sh run2.sh
```

But it won't run like I want (every two hours). I tried some kind of crontab, like

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/test_code/run2.sh
* * * * * PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /home/ubuntu/test_code/run2.sh
```

But I thinks I don't understand all this path stuff...

EDIT: the cronfile

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be 
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow command

#1 * * * * PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /home/ubuntu/test_code/run2.sh
* * * * * test_code/run2.sh &>cron.log
* * * * * pwd &>pwd.log
```

Comment: have a look at `man 5 crontab` on howto configure the cron entry. That `PATH` is definitely not in the right place.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to confess that I don't know what to do to correct this

Answer (score 0):

The script is called `run.sh` but the `cron` entry tries to run `run2.sh`. Is the `cron` entry referring to the proper script?

You did not say which user's `crontab` you are working with. If it is for user `ubuntu`, and that is the user ID you used to log in, then `crontab -e` is the command to edit the crontab. If you use `sudo`, then you are affecting the `root` user `crontab`, which has different permissions.

You do not need two entries to make this happen. Just delete the last line. I will show you how to set an environment variable in a `crontab` below.

Specifying `* * * * *` means "run my program every minute of every day, 24/7". To make it run every 2 hours instead, use `0 */2 * * *`. To learn more, see https://crontab.guru/every-2-hours

`Cron` runs commands from your home directory, so you can use a relative path to run a program under user `ubuntu`'s home directory.

Notice that I set the `PATH` environment variable, used by all `cron` entries, which might not be necessary, but should not hurt anything:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 */2 * * * test_code/run2.sh
```

To debug, append `&>cron.log` like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 */2 * * * test_code/run2.sh &>cron.log
```

Then from a terminal type:

```sh
$ tail -f cron.log
```

Let me know how you do with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rapid answer. Sorry it was a typo, it's run2.sh all the time !

What I did is get in my directory (/home/ubuntu/test_code), write crontab -e and edit the file.

I use your setting (juste use the "* * * * *" to not have to wait 2 hours), but it still doesn't work

Comment: Send the output of your command to a file by appending `&>cron.log`

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: when I run the script manually, it works (all the files I want are created and moved to the right folder), but it tell me this:
run2.sh: 1: !/bin/bash: not found

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the first character of the script, which should be `#`. Edit `run2.sh` and verify that the first character is actually `#`.

Comment: Just did it, the `cron.log` file has been created in the /home/ubuntu. But it is empty

Comment: Put this at the top of your `cron`: `MAILTO=email@example.com` (use your actual email). Hopefully your email is properly set up on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Ouuups, you're right, the `#` was missing ! But the `cron.log` is still empty and it doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an online server that I didn't install, so I've not set my email on this system

Comment: Make a new `cron` entry, like this: `0 * * * * pwd &>pwd.log` and check the output file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230698/discussion-between-mike-slinn-and-luc).